# drawing scatter plot with html5 canvas and pure javascript no libraries with logarithmic axes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, plot, scatter

I posting my question because I couldn't find info anywhere, most tutorials require the use of fancy libraries and I just wan't to draw a html5 canvas scatter plot from two json multidimensional arrays containing the following data example:

```
{ 'dataset1' [ { "p0" : "0.69", "log(p0)" : "14", "p0_name" : "cn95" }, ]
```

and for the other axis

```
 { "p1" : "0.69", "log(p1)" : "14", "p1_name" : "dn95" },
```

the example I'm trying to recreate is something like [this](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/people/pulsar/psrcat/proc_form.php?version=1.51&JName=JName&P0=P0&P1=P1&startUserDefined=true&c1_val=&c2_val=&c3_val=&c4_val=&sort_attr=jname&sort_order=asc&condition=&pulsar_names=&ephemeris=short&coords_unit=raj%2Fdecj&radius=&coords_1=&coords_2=&style=Long%20with%20last%20digit%20error&no_value=*&fsize=3&x_axis=p0&x_scale=linear&y_axis=p1&y_scale=linear&state=query&plot_bottom.x=55&plot_bottom.y=34).

The biggest problem I have is getting the canvas use logarithmic scales. You can see from the example link that that is required to see something from the data. A fiddle would be great to play with and create my own! This is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/3L4humdv/
and this is the data im using [link](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/research/pulsar/psrcat/proc_form.php?version=1.51&P0=P0&P1=P1&startUserDefined=true&c1_val=&c2_val=&c3_val=&c4_val=&sort_attr=jname&sort_order=asc&condition=&pulsar_names=&ephemeris=short&coords_unit=raj%2Fdecj&radius=&coords_1=&coords_2=&style=Long%20with%20last%20digit%20error&no_value=*&fsize=3&x_axis=&x_scale=linear&y_axis=&y_scale=linear&state=query&table_bottom.x=62&table_bottom.y=34)

Comment: Graphs are a pain to generate, especially nice ones, that's why most people use existing libraries to do so. Even the page you linked uses Highcharts for graphing.

Comment: I know but I wan't to learn without a library first I'm quite close I just need to know how to structure my Json object and how to create a function from there to calculate a logarithmic scale for the x and y axis. 

my structure for my json files should be something like this:
{ "p0" : "0.69", "log(p0)" : "14", "p0_name" : "cn95" },

My file so far: http://jsfiddle.net/9m1m8yLz/

Answer (score 3):

Canvas cannot use logarithmic scale out of the box, you'll have to provide a function for your points to scale them yourselves.

I would suggest following procedure:

- Have a function taking value of one axis and its max.
- Normalize inside the function
- Then apply logarithmic function to the value and return
- Use the normalized value with canvas width/height to plot the point

Use the same function for drawing the graph container as well as the points/lines etc.

As an example, with a "pseudo" (as in no particular purpose) log function:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    w = canvas.width,
    h = canvas.height - 10, // give room for point/text
    maxHeight = 1000,
    axisStep = 100;

function myLog(v, max) {
  var n = v / max;          // normalize
  return n * n * n;         // some log formula
}

// draw scale per axis step
for(var i = 0; i < maxHeight; i += axisStep) {

   // get normalized value, multiply with canvas height and reverse axis
  var y = h - myLog(i, maxHeight) * h;

  // show axis mark each 100
  ctx.moveTo(0, y);
  ctx.lineTo(20, y);
}

ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "red";

// some random points between 0 and max height
for(var x = 30; x < w; x += 30) {
  var v = Math.random() * maxHeight,   // some value
      y = h - myLog(v, maxHeight) * h; // convert to y in canvas
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 7, 7);
  ctx.fillText(v.toFixed(0), x + 9, y +7);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

The same applies to the x value. Just replace the log function here with one appropriate for your purpose.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This defiantly helps! I understand now that I have to normalize the value. But I think before I can start tackeling this problem I need the correct way to set up my json file it should be like I stated at the top of this question maybe you can make some sense out of my fiddle I tried to make it as clear as possible with the comments. http://jsfiddle.net/9m1m8yLz/ Appreciate the help so far! I understand your example :)

Comment: wow! Awesome thanks :). No my intention was to rebuild that fiddle to load two json objects:

one with the p0 values and one with the p1 values 
     { 'dataset1' [ { "p0" : "0.69", "log(p0)" : "14", "p0_name" : "cn95"   }, ]

the csv can be removed and my data needs to be rebuild but that I can do I just need to find a way that when my data is structured like that how do I then plot that data, the name for example I want to use to show on a tooltip but that something to worry about later. My first priority is to show the data :) thanks tho and I hope you understand my problem!

Comment: Ahh it's so frustrating I can't seem to plot anything from the data :'(

Comment: They seem to plot fine in my browsers (ff/chrome)? In any case, the numbers are stored as strings. String greater/lesser works different than numbers (ie. "2" > "100" = true, 2 > 100 = false). You need to convert (or better, store) all you number values as numbers, or convert them with parseFloat() before using them in comparisons.

Comment: They are being parsed! here:
   var data_JSON = document.getElementById('JSON').value;
   var obj = JSON.parse(data_JSON); 

   var data2_JSON = document.getElementById('JSON2').value;
   var obj2 = JSON.parse(data2_JSON); 

my problem now is to get the axis to be logarithmic you can see my fiddle on how far I am now. http://jsfiddle.net/3L4humdv/ I tried to use your solution but I can't seem to get the normalize function to work properly so that the points in my canvas are shown correctly

Comment: @Knopfler Well, the scale code works as I have proven in the example above (it's not a full solution, just to give an example of what is needed in general). I looked through the fiddle, but this is more a debug project. In essence: you are using the dataset values to draw onto canvas directly (scale marks etc.). You need to first map these values so that canvas represents a window of them (or the region you want to show). This will require a bit more code and is sort of out-of-scope for the question IMO. First normalize all the values, then scale and offset them relative to window, then draw.

Comment: Can't thank you enough Ken I think I get it now and will post my solution once I'm finished :) Cheers!